# Login with Facebook and Google in Xamarin Forms App and Azure Mobile Apps

Tags: xamarin.forms, facebook-login, azure-mobile-services, google-signin

I'm creating a Xamarin.Forms PCL/Android/iOS app. My app will uses Azure Mobile App for sync data and now I need to implement user login to sync peer-user data.

I already have configure my Azure Mobile App (server) to Facebook and Google login and it works, but now, I need to do this on mobile app.
[I did this](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users) and it works for Facebook (MobileServiceUser receives the token and userId) but not for google, because google do not uses webview for login anymore.

I've search a lot in goole, but I didn't find nothing to solution my case. [I found this](https://github.com/jsauve/OAuthTwoDemo.XForms) but it didn't work for me. I've tried the client-flow but not success.

Has someone the solution for this?

In my login page on mobile, I need a button for facebook and another for google.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure Mobile Apps uses Xamarin.Auth underneath for the authentication piece.  Once Xamarin.Auth is updated to support the appropriate webview, then Azure Mobile Apps will as well.

However, in any reasonable mobile app, you will want to implement client-side authentication.  In the case of client-side authentication, you use the provider SDK (Google or Facebook) to get the token in their approved way and then submit it to the mobile backend to swap it for a ZUMO token.

This method (including sample code for Facebook on iOS and Google on Android) is discussed in Chapter 2 of my book at http://aka.ms/zumobook.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Mobile Apps use a variety of external identity providers to support authenticating and authorizing application users, including Facebook, Google, Microsoft, Twitter, and Azure Active Directory. Permissions can be set on tables to restrict access to authenticated users only.
You can refer https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/authentication/azure/

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Auth 1.4.x supports Custom Tabs and SafariViewController, but no Xamarin.Forms support what most of the users want.
Xamarin.Forms support is in the 1.5.0-alpha soon to be released.